# Calling lua_getglobal() crashes unless followed by lua_pop()

Tags: lua

I just figured out my app sometimes crashes when `lua_getglobal(L, "name");` is called many times.

I tried placing `lua_pop(L, 1);` after `lua_getglobal(L, "name");` and it no longer crashes.

Can calling `lua_getglobal(L, "name");` many times cause memory leaks?

Does anybody have a clue why my app crashes without `lua_pop(L, 1);`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119155/lua-memory-leak-in-c-process

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lua has a ([implementation-defined](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lstate.h.html#BASIC_STACK_SIZE)) limited [stack size](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#4.2).  If you keep pushing onto the stack without ever popping, the stack will be full at some point and trying to push more will crash your program.

If you check the documentation for [`lua_getglobal`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_getglobal) you'll find “Pushes onto the stack the value of the global”.  You are responsible for removing it, either calling a function which implicitly pops it (e.g. `lua_pcall`) or by explictly popping it with `lua_pop`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <lua.hpp>

int main() {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    if (luaL_dostring(L, "name = 'Zack Lee'") != 0) {
        std::cerr << "lua:" << lua_tostring(L, -1) << '\n';
        lua_close(L);
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
        lua_getglobal(L, "name");
        std::cout << i << ' ' << lua_tostring(L, -1) << '\n';
      //lua_pop(L, 1);
    }

    lua_close(L);
}
```

```
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -I/usr/include/lua5.2/ test.cpp -llua5.2
$ ./a.out
0 Zack Lee
<...snip...>
41 Zack Lee
Segmentation fault
```

If I uncomment the `lua_pop` line, it works as expected.

You can also resize the Lua stack, but this has already been answered [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778678/can-i-resize-the-max-size-of-the-stack-when-using-lua-pushnumber).

Comment: Thank you so much that answered my question!